# How to detect (and silently drop) cross-origin requests to my server?

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, cross-domain

Looking at attacks like CSRF, BREACH, [a subset of XS-Leaks](https://xsleaks.dev/) and probably many more, a cross-origin request is always involved. I'd like to block such non-toplevel-<a> cross-origin requests (from <form>,<img>,<script>,<link>,fetch(),XMLHttpRequest,<a>-within-iframe and others) to my server (a simple express (node.js) application, but a general answer would be nice). By "block" I mean drop silently on the server side, without sending any response.

I've checked out the `Origin` HTTP header, but it isn't sent with <img> tags.
The `Referer` header is easy to omit on the attacker's site's side, so to reject all cross-origin requests I'd need to check that "Referer exists and is me", and that doesn't allow fresh GET requests (nor <a> top-level navigations from other sites).
The `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-site` response header and its supplementary headers are nice, but they don't help me avoid sending a response which the attacker can time from js / size as a man-in-the-middle - having the browser reject the content is irrelevant.

Is there an HTTP header I'm overlooking, which clearly identifies a cross-origin request?
Perhaps a browser-specific one?
Is there a plan to introduce one in the foreseeable future in either Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Does the [`Sec-Fetch-Mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Mode) header (or the related `Sec-Fetch-*` headers) fulfill your requirement?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Great, that works, thanks! No support for Safari, but so be it.

Comment: I'd be interested as well if you post the details of your solution as an answer.

Comment: As soon as I have something concrete, sure thing :)

Comment: Apparently, this approach is one of the recommended ways to mitigate Spectre-based SOP violations - see:
https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/mitigating-side-channel-attacks.html  
and:
https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-post-spectre-webdev/#:~:text=Decide%20when%20(not!)%20to%20respond%20to%20requests